# How to get Release Date Variable or Build Date Variable when a Release created

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to get the release start date or build date, and use this date string in my deployment app, but I didn't found it in the pre-defined variable wiki https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch

Any one knows how to get it? Or it doesn't exist the pre-defined variable of the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found how to do it! Any better ways are welcomed!

1. set the release name formate as $(Date:yyyyMMdd)
   [image]
2. Use $(Release.ReleaseName) in your deployment task of your pipeline

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please accept your solution [as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Comment: I got "invalid reference format", any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You always can get full information with rest api: [Get Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Small example to get created date and time:

1. Add to your release definition a new variable ([Release variables and debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell)). rl.CreatedDateTime in my case
2. Set access to the token on the job level

[image]

3. Add the following powershell inline script to update your variable.

   ```
   $user = ""
   $token = "$(System.AccessToken)"
   $teamProject = "$(System.TeamProject)"
   $releaseId = "$(Release.ReleaseId)"
   $orgUrl = "$(System.CollectionUri)"
   $orgUrlrel = $orgUrl -replace "dev", "vsrm.dev" 

   $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

   $uriGetRelease = "$orgUrlrel/$teamProject/_apis/release/releases/$releaseId"+"?api-version=5.1"

   $resultStatus = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriGetRelease -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

   [datetime]$releaseDate = $resultStatus.createdOn

   $setDateTimeVar = "##vso[task.setvariable variable=rl.CreatedDateTime]" + $releaseDate

   Write-Host $setDateTimeVar
   ```